# Вывести на экран 1 строку матрицы в обратном порядке

Tags: python

Помогите исправить код

```
import numpy as np 
c=np.random.randint(100, size=(4,5))
print(c)
print(c[::-1])
```

Comment: а так  `c[0,::-1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так, должно сработать

```
import numpy as np 
c=np.random.randint(100, size=(4,5))
print(c)
print(c[0,::-1]
```